# DRF restore_object() in ModelSerializer does not execute

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a wiki model which has two fields as follows.

```
class Wiki(models.Model):
  markup = models.TextField()
  rendered = models.TextField()
```

and a corresponding serializer, in which restore_object is supposed to auto fill rendered field.

```
class WikiSerializer(ModelSerializer):
  def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
    awiki = super(WikiSerializer, self).restore_object(attrs, instance)
    awiki.rendered = markdown(awiki.markup)
    return awiki

  class Meta:
    model = Wiki
```

@ shell,

```
$ awiki = WikiSerializer(data = {'markup' : '#hello world'})
$ awiki.errors
=> {'rendered': 'This field is required'}
```

Apparently the method restore_object is not being executed. Isn't restore_object used to create model object from given data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@okm thanks for informing that `restore_objct runs after validation`.

I solved the problem by making `rendered` field readonly. I need `rendered` field in serialized data so I could not exclude it.

```
class WikiSerializer(ModelSerializer):
  def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
    awiki = super(WikiSerializer, self).restore_object(attrs, instance)
    awiki.rendered = markdown(awiki.markup)
    return awiki

  class Meta:
    model = Wiki
    read_only_fields = ('rendered',)
```

Answer (score 1):

`restore_object` runs after validation which failed because of lack of `rendered` field. Try to use [`exclude` or `fields`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#specifying-which-fields-should-be-included) or specify the model field `rendered` to have `blank=True`:

> Note: When validation is applied to a ModelSerializer, both the
>   serializer fields, and their corresponding model fields must correctly
>   validate. If you have optional fields on your model, make sure to
>   correctly set blank=True on the model field, as well as setting
>   required=False on the serializer field.

Also, `class META` should be `class Meta`. Unlike `request.META`, Django model and DRF serializer use `Meta`.